# Передаю не правильный заголовок в POST запрос

Tags: c#, api, post

[Есть API переводчика](https://rapidapi.com/jenio-inc-jenio-inc-default/api/kiara-translate/endpoints)

В нем такой пример POST запроса на RestSharp (валидный ключ вложен):

```
var client = new RestClient("https://kiara-translate.p.rapidapi.com/get_translated/");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "kiara-translate.p.rapidapi.com");
request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "tb0d24d7fffmsh9be6b811c6b83dcp131c79jsn83b8a400788b");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{ "input": "We make the world a better place", "lang": "ja"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

У меня проблемы с строкой, а именно с ее форматом:

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{ "input": "We make the world a better place", "lang": "ja"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Тут должен передаваться параметр перевода и строка текста на перевод.
Вот что получается (путем обычного HttpWebRequest):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/iEowhw

> Specified value has invalid HTTP Header characters

Если не экранировать

> "

получается ошибка синтаксиса
Как правильно уложить запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ох и ужасная эта API, пришлось неслабо помучаться.

Дело в том, что стандартный строковый запрос с генерирует вот такой заголовок

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Это вообще настолько стандарт, насколько это возможно, но!

Сервер возвращает:

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

Еще приключений добавили примеры запросов на сайте, которые у них вообще все с ошибками, даже для JavaScript. Но с помощью примеров на JS мне удалось покидать запросы и все-таки добиться от сервера ответа.

А работать оно начало только тогда, когда я явным образом переопределил `Content-Type` вот на такой.

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Ребята эти редкие извращенцы, но мы и не таких видали.

---

Вот код для консольного приложение .NET Core 3.1, C# 8.0

Классы данных запроса и ответа

```csharp
public class TestJsonRequest
{
    [JsonPropertyName("input")]
    public string Input { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("lang")]
    public string Lang { get; set; }
}

public class TestJsonResponse
{
    [JsonPropertyName("response")]
    public string ResponseStatus { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("source_lang")]
    public string SourceLang { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("status")]
    public int Status { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("target_lang")]
    public string TargetLang { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("translated")]
    public string Translated { get; set; }
}
```

Сам код

```csharp
class Program
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestJsonRequest requestData = new TestJsonRequest
        {
            Input = "We make the world a better place",
            Lang = "ru"
        };
        string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestData);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        try
        {
            string jsonResponse = await PostJsonAsync("https://kiara-translate.p.rapidapi.com/get_translated/", json);
            Console.WriteLine(jsonResponse);
            TestJsonResponse response = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestJsonResponse>(jsonResponse);
            Console.WriteLine("ResponseStatus: {0}", response.ResponseStatus);
            Console.WriteLine("SourceLang: {0}", response.SourceLang);
            Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", response.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("TargetLang: {0}", response.TargetLang);
            Console.WriteLine("Text: {0}", response.Text);
            Console.WriteLine("Translated: {0}", response.Translated);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task<string> PostJsonAsync(string url, string json)
    {
        using HttpContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
        request.Content = content;
        request.Headers.Add("x-rapidapi-host", "kiara-translate.p.rapidapi.com");
        request.Headers.Add("x-rapidapi-key", "b0d24d7fffmsh9be6b811c6b83dcp131c79jsn83b8a400788b");
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"); // костыль
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
        //response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
{"input":"We make the world a better place","lang":"ru"}
{"text": "We make the world a better place", "translated": "\u041c\u044b \u0434\u0435\u043b\u0430\u0435\u043c \u043c\u0438\u0440 \u043b\u0443\u0447\u0448\u0435", "target_lang": "ru", "source_lang": "en", "response": "Successful", "status": 200}
ResponseStatus: Successful
SourceLang: en
Status: 200
TargetLang: ru
Text: We make the world a better place
Translated: Мы делаем мир лучше
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше время! Ушел пробовать

Comment: Ну почему костыль, вполне ожидаемое для некоторых API поведения, требует исключительно MIME тип, а не кодировку. Чтоб в C# убрать кодировку из `ContentType` достаточно сделать `new StringContent(json)` и дальше задать прям ему MIME (`content.Headers.ContentType = ...`).  Сам же код, как по мне можно сократить примерно до [такого](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w2HCGH) состояния, а если убрать ужасный десериализатор от Microsoft, то еще короче и удобней будет). То есть задавать каждому запросу ключ и заголовки бессмысленно, лучше сразу инициализировать `HttpClient` с нужными данными.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я же не в курсе, автор только в эту API собирается постить, или еще куда. Но да, можно и дефолтными заголовками обойтись. И десереализатор у Microsoft крутой и быстрый, не надо вот тут на него наговаривать. На вкус и цвет тоаварищей нет. При условии .NET Core не вижу смысла никакого использовать Newtonsoft. (совсем).

Comment: Хорошо, вот вам задача `TestJsonResponse` - это ответ от сервера, который мы не в праве редактировать, он должен быть закрыт для записи, лишь чтение. Как вы такое сделаете с данным сериализатором? Ну и эти ужасные атрибуты.. Про них мы говорили, но все же. Простите, но тут уже не вкус, а качество написания кода, да для некоторых проектов может быть, но в большинстве других это не удобно на данном этапе, ибо либо лезь в настройки и переопределяй там все (написав кучу лишнего), либо вообще не можешь это сделать, ибо не реализовано. Но спорить не буду, лишь говорю, что на Json.net будет чище.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ для моих 300 запросов за 5 секунд оно подходит и работает, и проект весит на 600кб меньше, чем с NuGet пакетом. Допилят, доработают, но меня и то что есть на 100% устраивает. Я уверен, вы не одиноки в своем мнении, которое наверняка доведено до разработчиков, я лишь рассуждаю в рамках того, что вижу и использую сам.

Comment: Ну я вон вам дал задачу выше, попробуйте сделать, ибо открытый ответ от сервера - это большая дыра. А размер, ну серьезно, кто сейчас экономит на кб? Я понимаю мб/гб, но кб.... Короче лично я вижу одни минусы в нем, увы, вы может иначе и вам он подходит, но это не значит, что он подходит всем и не стоит его так яро нахваливать и всем советовать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я начал писать код, когда у могео компа было 640кб оперативы+2МБ кучи, а на жестком диске было 40МБ. И я научился четко видеть, куда и когда девается память. Когда я могу просто выбросить лишнее, я выбрасываю. Когда после выбрасывания оно еще быстрее начинает работать, я вообще перестаю понимать, о чем вы говорите. Какие лишние атрибуты? Я написал 1 раз и забыл, а работает быстрее и жрет меньше оперативы - всегда. А всякие `TestJsonResponse` я пишу сам, и сам решаю, где, что и когда открыто или закрыто. Мы с вами в разных мирах, и в ваш мир суровых разработчиков я пока не собираюсь.

Comment: Я не пойму, чего вы со мной вечно спорите? Я под вашим ответом дал то, что мне изначально не нравиться не только для вас, но и для других читателей. Я не вижу смысла в новомодном сериализаторе от Microsoft, это мой выбор и выбор каждого другого человека, зачем вы яростно всем его навязываете и так отстаиваете свое мнение? Представьте себе, есть те, кто с ним не согласен и я один из них, также как и вы не согласны с моим мнением, но я же вам не говорю что выкидывайте его нафиг и используйте JSON.Net, нет, я лишь обмолвился что можно проще и не стоит всем навязывать свое мнение.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ _не стоит всем навязывать свое мнение_ так не навязывайте тогда. JSON.NET пора к динозаврам. Не смотря на то, что это на сегодняшний день лучший сериализатор, он устарел, и учиться надо использовать `System.Text.Json` а не, с чего уже давно один за одним мигрируют проекты. В высоконагруженных кор-дотнетах его уже почти нет, скоро и на десктопах не станет. Рано или поздно и вы последуете моде. Про споры, вы пришли ко мне в комменты, а не я к вам. И я прав, а вы нет, потому что я рекомендую перспективное API, а вы если и не устаревшее, то уже устаревающее. Пишу со всем уважением.

Comment: Прикол в том, что я не советую, я почти во всех ответах указывают что JSON.NET один из способов работы с JSON, а вы, почти в любой удобный случай пишете "Используйте `System.Text.Json` он удобный и быстрый", что является навязыванием своего мнения. SO это свободная площадка, где каждый в праве выбирать чего ему надо, я пойму еще `HttpClient`, да, другие устарели и это лучший вариант, но JSON, я не согласен с этим, он может и производительней, но не удобней и не функциональней (задача выше, решили?). По поводу спора - я изначально спорил? Это вы написали `не надо вот тут на него наговаривать`.

Comment: Короче это может на долго затянуться, хотите продолжение - делайте чат, поговорим, тут я не вижу смысла дальнейшей дискуссии. ибо у вас свое мнение, у меня свое, может и будет все рано или поздно на творение майкрософта, перейду с удовольствием когда допилят, но пока, это костыль. Так что вам всего наилучшего и научитесь принимать стороннее мнение что-ли, не воспринимая все изначально в штыки.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ производительность - согласен, удобство - согласен, недопиленность - тоже согласен. Здесь нет разногласий. Но я буду советовать то, в чем вижу смысл. Это мое мнение и моя личная позиция. Я ни кого не могу даже физически принудить ее принять, скорее наоборот, пусть каждый думает своей головой. И вы не переживайте об этом, от того что на SO будет больше материалов про новый сериализатор - это, я считаю - хорошо, и дальше буду стараться в это вкладываться. А про первое ньютоновское детище и так их навалом.